# Change backgroundImage of right Nav button in Titanium - iPhone

Tags: iphone, titanium

I am developing an iPhone app using Titanium Alloy.

My problem is that I would like to change the backgroundImage of rightNav button.

I am using the rightNav button as a Filter button. My Filter button is placed in a window which also has a table. Once the filter button is clicked a new window is opened where the user can make some selections. Once the selection is made, the table on the previous page is refreshed based on the selections made and I would like to change the backgroundImage of the rightNav button to show that some selections have been applied. But I am unable to do so.

My code :

```
if ((screenType === "parentWindow") {
    $.rightNav.visible = true;
    $.rightNav.backgroundImage = "/images/buttons/filterOff.png";       
} else if ((screenType === "childWindow")) {
    $.rightNav.visible = true;
    $.rightNav.backgroundImage = "/images/buttons/filterOn.png";
}
```

The backgroundImage of the rightNav button is set first time and then it is not changed. I have tried to make it null and then set it again but it does not work.

Please help.

Other details :
Titanium Command-Line Interface, CLI version 4.0.0, Titanium SDK version 4.0.0.RC, Mac OS X 10.10

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `image` property .

Comment: Thanks. Thats it. It worked! Such a simple thing only if you know the solution :-)!